# Click events not working above the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have one leaflet map and 2 div section with some content.

```
<body>      
    <div class="row showEquipmentDetails" style="margin:10px;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showEquipmentDetails()" style="float:right"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="EquipmentContent row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="float:right;background:#dff0ff;">  
            <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 cl-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <label class="equipmentHeaderlable">Name</label>
                <label class="equipmentHeaderValues">SSS</label>
            </section>  
            <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 cl-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <label class="equipmentHeaderlable">Speed</label>
                <label class="equipmentHeaderValues">SSS</label>
            </section>                  
            <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 cl-md-1 col-lg-1">
                <button type="button" style="display: inline-block;float:right;" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="hideEquipmentDetails()"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="map">  
    </div>
</body>

<script>
$('.EquipmentContent').hide();
function showEquipmentDetails(){
$('.showEquipmentDetails').hide();
$('.EquipmentContent').show();
}
function hideEquipmentDetails(){
$('.showEquipmentDetails').show();
$('.EquipmentContent').hide();
}
</script>
```

Am doing hide and show of 2 div section its placed on out side of the map. But I need to hide and show it above the map,so I wrote like this

```
<div id="map">  
    <div class="row" style="margin:10px;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary showEquipmentDetails" onclick="showEquipmentDetails()" style="float:right"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="EquipmentContent row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="float:right;background:#dff0ff;">  
            <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 cl-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <label class="equipmentHeaderlable">Name</label>
                <label class="equipmentHeaderValues">SSS</label>
            </section>  
            <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 cl-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <label class="equipmentHeaderlable">Speed</label>
                <label class="equipmentHeaderValues">SSS</label>
            </section>                  
            <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 cl-md-1 col-lg-1">
                <button type="button" style="display: inline-block;float:right;" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="hideEquipmentDetails()"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

But click events are not working on map. when I click on first button, map is getting zoomed .click events are not fired. why? How can I achieve it?any suggestion?Thanks!!

Comment: This is not depicting your problem area in specific. There must be some more scripts or other scripts which are probably causing the problem. You need to specify some more details.

Comment: Just on assumption that you have implemented the map properly, I can suggest that put your click event function call within the script where the map is getting loaded , means make sure when the map is loaded then the click events are triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution.
By adding the following style I am getting the expected result

```
.showEquipmentDetails,.EquipmentContent{
position:absolute;
z-index:9;
width:98%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Map is not loading to me. But check whether this solution is working for you,

```js
var mymap = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);



$('.EquipmentContent').hide();


function showEquipmentDetails(){
$('.showEquipmentDetails').hide();
$('.EquipmentContent').show();
}

function hideEquipmentDetails(){
$('.showEquipmentDetails').show();
$('.EquipmentContent').hide();
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 650px;
  height: 350px;
  position:relative
}
#map { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
 }

 
.EquipmentContent { 
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top:8px;
  left: 45px;
 }
 
 .showEquipmentDetails { 
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top:8px;
  left: 45px
 }
 
 #EquipmentContent {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
   
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
   
   
<div id="container">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div class="EquipmentContent row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style=";background:#dff0ff;">  
            <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 cl-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <label class="equipmentHeaderlable">Name</label>
                <label class="equipmentHeaderValues">SSS</label>
            </section>  
            <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 cl-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <label class="equipmentHeaderlable">Speed</label>
                <label class="equipmentHeaderValues">SSS</label>
            </section>                  
            <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 cl-md-1 col-lg-1">
                <button type="button" style="display: inline-block;" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="hideEquipmentDetails()"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary showEquipmentDetails" onclick="showEquipmentDetails()" ><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    
</div>
```